# XMLSerializer Десериализация двух элементов в один список

Tags: c#, xml

Можно ли как-то произвести десериализацию разных по названию элементов, но одинакового содержимого в один список?

**XML**

```
<template>
<images>
<small>
</small>
<large>
</large>
<small>
</small>
<large>
</large>
</images>
</template>
```

**CODE**

```
public class myclass
{
[XmlElement("small")]
[XmlElement("large")]
ObservableCollection<MyImage> myimage
{get;set;}
}
```

При таком определении, он ругается, что необходимо указать `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute` Хотя как мне кажется, он тут не причем...

Писать свой десериализатор очень не хочется.

PS: Или, конечно, как вариант, можно попробовать сделать два разных списка, а потом в ListView из привязать мультибиндингом? Как правильнее подойти к этому вопросу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сгенерировал набор классов по представленному XML с помощью Студии: Edit > Paste Special > Paste XML As Classes. Обработал их напильником, убрав все лишние атрибуты и поля.

Также я предположил, что элементы должны содержать в себе вложенные свойства. Примерно так:

```
<template>
  <images>
    <small>
      <size>100</size>
    </small>
    <large>
      <size>1000</size>
    </large>
    <small>
      <size>110</size>
    </small>
    <large>
      <size>1100</size>
    </large>
  </images>
</template>
```

В итоге у меня получился такой набор классов:

```
[XmlRoot("template")]
public class Template
{
    [XmlElement("images")]
    public TemplateImages Images { get; set; }
}
public class TemplateImages
{
    [XmlElement("large", typeof(Image))]
    [XmlElement("small", typeof(Image))]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
    public Image[] Items { get; set; }

    //[XmlElement("ItemsElementName")]
    //[XmlIgnore()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName { get; set; }
}
public enum ItemsChoiceType
{
    large,
    small,
}
public class Image
{
    [XmlElement("size")]
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Вроде работает и без закомментированных атрибутов.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Template));
    var template = (Template)xs.Deserialize(fs);

    foreach (var item in template.Images.Items)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Size);

    foreach (var name in template.Images.ItemsElementName)
        Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: Очень похоже на правду, но почему-то выдает при попытке создания сериализатора ошибку "NullReferenceException". Чуть позже попробую выдернуть суть кода из проекта и напишу в своем вопросе. При этом, если десериализовать только с одного элемента - то все нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Использовался список класса observablecollection. С ним так и не получилось.