# Проблема ObservableCollection<T> Deserialize

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Не могу разобраться с проблемой десериализации колекции объектов.

Продолжение темы [XMLSerializer Десериализация двух элементов в один список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816521/xmlserializer-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Прошлый вариант помог, объект стал десериализоваться, однако все же необходимо не обычный массив, а именно observablecollection

При попытке изменить свойства на данный тип, происходит падение `NullReferenceException` Провозился весь день, но так и не понял из-за чего. Поиск по интернету не навел меня на мысль. Последняя надежда на вас.

Код десериализуемого объекта:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("icons", Namespace = "interfaces.xsd")]
public class RibbonInterface : Notifier
{
    public ObservableCollection<Icon> _Icons;
    [XmlElement("small", typeof(Icon))]
    [XmlElement("large", typeof(Icon))]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
    public ObservableCollection<Icon> Icons
    {
        get
        {
            return _Icons;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _Icons, value, "Icons");
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ItemChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public enum ItemChoiceType
{
    small,
    large
}
```

Начало десериализации выглядит так:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(ofd.FileName);
var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ws", "interfaces.xsd");
var xmlReader = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ws:template/ws:icons", ns).CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RibbonInterface));
Model.InterfaceImages = (RibbonInterface)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

Падение происходит на строке `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RibbonInterface));` Т.е. до самого построения объекта даже не дошли. Где-то проблема с описанием десериализуемого объекта.

На всякий случай класс Notifier

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string Name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Name не может быть NULL или пустым");

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
        }
    }

    public void Set(ref ObservableCollection<Icon> Property, ObservableCollection<Icon> Value, string Name)
    {
        if (Property != Value)
        {
            Property = Value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё ж таки событие лучше вызывать так: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, ...)`

Comment: В 2013 студии этого сделать не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте так, как советует в своём ответе VladD. В модели для деесериализации используйте массив

```
public Icon[] Icons { ... }
```

После десериализации данные загружаем в коллекцию нужного типа:

```
var icons = new ObservableCollection<Icon>(ribbonInterface.Icons);
```

---

Следует пообщаться с тем, кто предоставляет xml в таком виде. И договориться об его изменении.

Дело в том, что такая форма неправильная. Есть стандартные наработанные практики представления xml. Смотрите, например, [xml patterns](http://www.xmlpatterns.com/patterns.shtml). Элементы одного типа должны иметь одинаковые названия. Элементы `large` и `small` очевидно описывают изображения. Стало быть, должны иметь название `image` или `icon`. А размер должен быть их атрибутом (или вложенным элементом).

```
<image size="large">...</image>
<image size="small">...</image>
```

Тогда десериализация будет лёгкой и приятной.

---

В предыдущем вопросе вы упомянули

> Писать свой десериализатор очень не хочется.

Между тем, тут вы уже наваяли кучу кода с использованием `XmlDocument` и `XmlReader`. Написанный вручную код с применением LinqToXml может оказаться короче и быть понятнее:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var images = xml
    .Elements("images")
    .Elements()
    .Select(e => new Image
    {
        Size = (int)e.Element("size"),
        // Param2 = (double)e.Element("dpi")
    });

var icons = new ObservableCollection<Image>(images);
```

В качестве входного xml я использовал пример из моего ответа из прошлой темы.

Недостаток этого кода в том, что понадобится строка кода на чтение каждого вложенного узла для инициализации каждого свойства. Однако, при применении десериализатора наверняка тоже понадобится строка кода с указанием нужного имени/типа `XmlElement/XmlAttribute`:

```
[XmlElement("size")] // <-- лишняя строка, которая нужна при использовании XmlSerializer
                     // но не нужна при ручном чтении
public int Size { get; set; }
```

---

Теперь покритикуем ваш код начала десериализации.

Во-первых, не используйте `XmlDocument` - он считается устаревшим. Лучше возьмите `XDocument/XElement` (LinqToXml).

Во-вторых, раз уж всё равно используется `XmlReader`, то можно обойтись только им. Что-то вроде:

```
using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("icons", "interfaces.xsd"))
    {
        // десериализация
    }
}
```

Всегда освобождайте ресурсы! `XmlReader` является disposable объектом. Значит, нужно вызвать в конце его использования метод `Dispose`. Или, что лучше, обернуть его в оператор `using`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, судя по всему, в том, что вы хотите сериализовать UI-объект. UI-объекты не предназначены для сериализации.

Говоря более широко, невозможно сериализовать класс, который не было создан для сериализации. Для корректной сериализации в классе не должно быть интерфейсов, непубличных полей/свойств, должен быть конструктор без параметров, класс должен быть доступен как `public` и т. п. Не стоит надеяться, что произвольный чужой класс будет подходить для этого.

Ну и не стоит пытаться <s>натянуть сову на глобус</s> пытаться сломать семантику своего класса, убрав параметры из конструктора и сделав все поля публичными только для того, чтобы его можно было сериализовать.

Вместо этого лучше всего написать DTO-класс, не содержащий логики, и сериализовать его.

А UI-объекты вообще лучше не сериализовать, в рамках MVVM нужно серализовать модельные объекты, и строить из них VM, и соответственно и UI.

Comment: Хотелось по простому решить проблему. Даже особо проверок намвалидные значения не делаю. Однако десериализация в ObservableCollection проходит нормально, если не использовать XmlChoiceIdentifier

Comment: @pincher1519: Ну, «по-простому» и означает «использовать путь, который не гарантировано приведёт решению вопроса». Если делать правильно, проблем не будет.